# How to run iOS app over Wi-Fi in xcode without connecting the device to the Macbook using USB cable?

Tags: xcode

How do I wirelessly connect my iPad to Xcode? It is required of me to connect my device to my Macbook using USB cable first, but my USB port is not working at all and it is impossible for me to do so. I looked everywhere on the web but cannot seem to get it working.

Answer (score 1):

in Xcode while the device is connected via cable if you open `Window` -> `Devices and Simulators` or `shift + cmd + ⬆` there is a checkbox to connect via network